# Vue.js transitions not working in Laravel Blade + Sass

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2, laravel-blade

My Google search didn't come up with any answer to is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong.

My HTML:

```
<a v-on:click="showInformation = !showInformation">Show / Hide</a>
<transition name="fade">
    <p class='further-info' v-if="!showInformation">Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</transition>
```

EDIT: Just found out that it works like this:

```
<transition name="fade">
    <div v-if="!showInformation">
        <p class='further-info'>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    </div>
</transition>
```

This is not documented in the Vue.js documentation and it's clearly shown that it should work as the first example. Is this expected in my case?

My SASS:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active
    transition: opacity .5s

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to
    opacity: 0
```

Pretty straight forward, but I may be doing something wrong. Whenever I click the button the `p` shows and hides correctly, but without any transition effect.

Using:

```
Laravel 5.7.9
Vue.js 2.9.6 (with ES6)
Sass 1.14.2 (but not relevant since it complies the transition code correctly)
The HTML file is written a blade template file
```

Comment: Found out that it works if I put the transition class, than another class inside with the `v-if` and then the `p` ... This is not shown in the Transitions Documentation and there it is clearly shown that it has to work without any additional classes. Is that expected in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the v-if to a v-show. This way the element exists in the page even though it's not displayed.